# Decorator Design - Option Strict On disallows narrowing

Tags: .net

I work thru a design pattern book and just cannot reply the decorator class example. I tried the example 1by1 here is the example (shortend):

> ```
> Public Interface TakeHomePay
> Function GetTakeHomePay() As Double 
> End Interface
>
> Public Class Employee : Implements TakeHomePay
> Private m_GrossWage As Double
> Private m_NetWage As Double
> Public Function GetTakeHomePay() As Double Implements TakeHomePay.GetTakeHomePay
>     Return m_NetWage
> End Function End Class
>
> Public MustInherit Class WageAdjustment : Implements TakeHomePay
> Protected m_TakeHomePay As TakeHomePay
> Public Sub New(ByRef thp As TakeHomePay)
>     m_TakeHomePay = thp
> End Sub
> Public Function GetTakeHomePay() As Double Implements TakeHomePay.GetTakeHomePay
>     Return m_TakeHomePay.GetTakeHomePay
> End Function 
> End Class
>
> Public Class CountryTax : Inherits WageAdjustment
> Private m_CountryName As String
>
> Public Sub New(ByRef thp As TakeHomePay, ByVal CountryName As String)
>     MyBase.New(thp)
>     m_CountryName = CountryName
> End Sub
>
> Public Sub DeductTax()
>     'something
> End Sub End Class
> ```

The employee class is the concrete class, the WageAdjustment Class is the decorator Class and the CountryTax class is the decorator subclass. My problem is, as soon as I try to use this in my client like

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim objEmployee As New Employee
    Dim objCountryTax As CountryTax
    objCountryTax = New CountryTax(objEmployee, "USA")
End Sub
```

`objEmployee` in the line "`objCountryTax = New CountryTax(objEmployee, "USA")`" gives me the error:

> "Option Strict On disallows narrowing from type 'TakeHomePay' to type
>   'Employee' in copying the value of ByRef parameter thp' back to the
>   matching argument"

MSDN says that reverse conversion of the ByRef Paramenter (thp) is narrowing. I just cannot see, why the object (based on the interface) is narrowed (maybe I just dont get the definition of narrowing though...) according to the book this should work perfect but the book is 8 years old, so maybe there has been some changes in vs or .NET. I am using vs 2012. Could anyone tell me why this is not working and how I can get it work?

Comment: ByRef is unnecessary and incorrect.  Replace with ByVal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to rely on an 8-year old book. You can find more recent examples of the decorator pattern online, for example, [here](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx).

The reason that this is a narrowing conversion is that the signature of the constructor being called is:

```
Public Sub New(ByRef thp As TakeHomePay, ByVal CountryName As String)
```

And you're calling it with

```
objCountryTax = New CountryTax(objEmployee, "USA")
```

Since the first parameter is `ByRef`, the constructor is allowed to reassign the `objEmployee` reference that you are passing. That reassignment will be reflected in `objEmployee`.

However `objEmployee` is declared to be of type `Employee`, but the constructor knows only that it is a `TakeHomePay` instance. The constructor could therefore attempt to reassign it as:

```
thp = New SomeOtherClassThatImplementsTakeHomePay()
```

And that assignment would propagate to `objEmployee`. But you can't cram that new object into an `Employee` reference, because the former may not be assignable to the latter.

Unless there's a specific reason for the parameter to be `ByRef`, changing it to `ByVal` should solve the problem. The problem is caused in the `ByRef` copying the `thp` parameter back into the `objEmployee` reference.